# C# Regex Replace Either Or With Overlapping Match Phrases

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text like so:

```
string[] words = new string[] { "Billy", "Billy Jr.", "party" };
string s = "<p>Billy and Billy Jr. are both coming to the party.</p>";
```

I want to do a C# regex to highlight the words in the array:

```
string s = "<p><span>Billy</span> and <span>Billy Jr.</span> are both coming to the <span>party</span>.";
```

I tried using a foreach loop:

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    s = Regex.Replace(s, word, "<span>$&</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

But the problem is, when I do Billy, it will match on Billy Jr. and that phrase will get wrapped twice. How do I accomplish what I want?

Comment: Don't use a foreach loop. Build an alternation with the longest items first: `Billy Jr\.|Billy|party` and parse the string only once.

Comment: `s = Regex.Replace(s, string.Join("|", words.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Length).Select(Regex.Escape), "<span>$&</span>, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping and doing a regex three times, you can make one single regex which will match graduately:

```
(Billy Jr\.|Billy|party)
```

If you use this, it will match `Billy Jr.` before `Billy`, so if the first is found, it will only replace that one.

And the [regex101 proof](https://regex101.com/r/oOi3oY/1).

---

To shamelessly steal [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr)s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399501/c-sharp-regex-replace-either-or-with-overlapping-match-phrases/43399556#comment73859825_43399501) (which does what I wrote above), you can do this in C#:

```
s = Regex.Replace
    ( s
    , string.Join
      ( "|"
      , words.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
             .Select(Regex.Escape)
      , "<span>$&</span>"
      , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    );
```

What it does: it creates a regular expression based on the words array. It first sorts the array on longest first, to prevent the 'Billy' problem. Then it calls `Regex.Escape` on every word to escape the `.`. Then it uses the generated regular expression to do the replace.

Comment: I was going to tell you to use it anyway ;)

Comment: Does this work in C#? Your regex101 proof looks like it's in php.

Comment: PHP uses a slightly different syntax, but this one will work without problems in C# too.

Comment: It [will work in .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Billy+Jr%5c.%7cBilly%7cparty&i=%3cp%3eBilly+and+Billy+Jr.+are+both+coming+to+the+party.%3c%2fp%3e&r=%3cspan%3e%24%26%3c%2fspan%3e).